# SVN show files in working directory which are out of date

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am playing around with SVN trying to get a better feel for how it works.  I added some files to my repository and checked them out into 2 separate working directories.  For working directory 1 I am using my SQL client software (Aqua Data Studio) to modify the file and working directory 2 I am just using Windows Explorer with TortoiseSVN.

My question is, does SVN or the clients built on top of it, never show when a file in your working copy is out of date?  If I make a change in working directory 1 and commit I would expect to see working directory 2 notify me that my working copy is out of date with the repository.  Is this ever the case?  Is there any way to tell which files in my working directories are out of date or do I just need to be careful to always update prior to making a change to a file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `svn status --show-updates`

[EDIT] I didn't notice at first that you were using Windows, but this command should work for others running OSX or Linux

Comment: or "svn st -u"  Items that have modifications in the repository will have a * next to them.

Comment: Thanks!!!! Just to add to this, `svn status --show-updates | grep -v ^\?` will show all but files "not under version control" (indicated by ?, and consequently ignored') On linux/mac anyway. Could download cygwin for windows as well and install subversion with it; should give you the same capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

With TortoiseSVN, use the "Check for Modifications" command, then hit the "Check Repository" button.

Comment: Thanks, seems like TortoiseSVN is providing a graphical front end to the command provided by shiftycow and Mark.

Answer (score 1):

No, You will not see in your local working folder whether the repository contains a newer version.

SVN will check prior to committing your changes whether the server version is newer. It is good practice to update and commit frequently.

As you are on Windows you might want to try [**CommitMonitor**](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor), a tool written by the author of TortoiseSVN that notifies you about commits to SVN repositories.

Comment: Thanks, I had heard about that tool from reading other SVN related questions on SO.  I will check it out.